# ASP.NET MVC server-side processing of Google search results

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, server-side

This is probably a really simple question but...

I would like to do a Google image search (performed by Javascript as there is no other supported option right?) and resize the images on the server-side.

My first thought was to have the Javascript generate links like this:

> http://example.com/Resize.mvc/(link)

However, there were some problems with this when I passed the link (HTML 400 errors) that even URL encoding didn't seem to get over, and besides, there is no security stopping someone passing their own link in etc.

So how do I run the Javascript search server-side and do all processing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should cannibalize [this API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/google_image_search_api.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - this is a possible solution but I gather I then have to follow each time the Google results format changes and update the API.  Still if nothing more straightforward presents itself...